# Which one of the following logical propositions is to be preferred?

Tags: logic, notation, arithmetic, math-history, peano-axioms

I'm trying to update the symbolism of [Giuseppe Peano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Peano)'s "Arithmetices Principia", to make the translation freely available. Might I ask you, which of the following might be a correct mathematical reasoning? Since the original symbolism has bi-fold meanings. I suppose the symbolism should be updated as either one of the following:

- $(\alpha \xrightarrow[\forall x]{} \beta) = [(\overline{x} \in \alpha) \rightarrow (\overline{x} \in \beta)]$
- $(\alpha \underset{\forall \text{x}}\subset \beta) = [(\overline{x} \in \alpha) \rightarrow (\overline{x} \in \beta)]$

Is any of them non-sense, or could any of them be preferred?

If you are interested, the line I am trying to translate can be found as the line numbered with "**63.**", in [the original manuscript](https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog) on page "**XII**".

## *P.S. | Notation:*

- $\overline{x} \in a$ means ... *those $x$ such that $a$, or solutions, or roots of the condition $a$, indicates the class consisting of individuals which satisfy the condition $a$.*
- The sign $\subset$ means ... *is contained. Thus $a \subset b$ means the class $a$ is contained in the class $b$.*

If the propositions $a,b$ contain the indeterminate quantity $x$, that is, express conditions on these objects, then:

- $a \xrightarrow[\forall x]{} b$ means ... *whatever the $x$ from propositions $a$ one deduces $b$.*

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can take into account that already into [Principia Mathematica](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/) W&R introduced the notation $\varphi x \supset_x \psi x$ [i.e. $\varphi x \to_x \psi x$] for : $\forall x (\varphi x \supset \psi x)$.

Comment: But it seems to me that you are "mixing up" the already existsing symbols ... If $\alpha \subset \beta$ express the *inclusion* of class $\alpha$ into class $\beta$, this is "usually" defined as : $\forall x [(x \in \alpha) \to (x \in \beta))$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for your comments. I didn't know about the interesting article in the *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy*, which you mentioned.

The document I am referring to, however, is not by Russel & Whitehead (even though the article mentions that a certain amount of symbolism has been taken from Peano).

About your second comment: I agree with your expertise. However, to make my question more clear; I have added a reference to the full line "**63.**",  of which the symbolism I am trying to translate. Which one of the translation-versions would you think is (not) correct?

Comment: My comments are intended to stress the (for sure known to you) fact that there are already "modern" counterpart of Peano's symbols ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for that, I am not good at many things. Reading their Principia might perhaps indeed help to "update" the line in question, as well. However, I deem myself not capable of performing fundamental &/or large theoretical mathematical advancements; e.g. to synthesize the modern counterparts in dialogue with Peano's work. My aim is simply to practically update the manuscript to currently canonically-used symbolism; thus to historically remain with Peano's document.

Comment: My guess: $\alpha \subset \beta$ or $\forall x:[x\in \alpha \implies x\in \beta]$

Comment: @DanChristensen Thank you for your comment. Are you familiar with the notation used below by Mauro ALLEGRANZA? For the updating of the symbolism, it would be most interesting to use the most standard notation. Could you perhaps give your experience on these differences as well?

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*

You have to note that Peano's "inverted-C" symbols plays a double role.

Regarding *propositions* :

> $a \supset b$, with $a,b \in \mathsf P$ [where $\mathsf P$ stands for *propositio*]

has to be read as : "$a$ *deducitur* $b$", i.e. (more or less) our : $a \to b$ [see : page VIII].

Regarding *classes* :

> $a \supset b$, with $a,b \in \mathsf K$ [where $\mathsf K$ stands for *classis*]

has to be read as : "$a$ *continetur in* $b$", i.e. our : $a \subseteq b$ [see : page XI].

The two "roles" are linked into (slightly "modernized") :

> 50. $\ a,b \in \mathsf K \ [ \ a \supset b . \equiv . (x \in a \supset_x x \in b) \ ]$.

We have to note that Peano uses the same "style" of variables both for proposition and classes.

In [see : page XII] :

> 63. $\alpha \supset_x \beta . \equiv . [x \in \alpha] \supset [x \in \beta]$

we have to be careful to read the "complex" symbol $[x \in \alpha]$ as denoting :

> "*ea $x$ quibus* $a$" (more or less : "those $x$ such that $a$") i.e. "*classem significat  individuis constitutam, quae conditioni $a$ satisfaciunt*"

i.e. "the class of all those individuals that satisfy $a$".

Thus, we have not to use $a$ in the "propositional context" : $a \supset b$ and in the "class context" : $x \in a$, without some care.

W&R used $\psi x$ to express the *condition* "involving" $x$ and $\hat x \psi x$ for the *class* of all those $x$ such that $\psi x$ holds.

Thus, a "possible translation" of 63 above can be :

> > $\alpha \to_x \beta . \equiv . (x \in \hat \alpha \subset x \in \hat \beta)$,

where I've "reversed" the "inclusion" symbol (following modern practice) and I've "modernized" the conditional sign into : $\alpha \supset_x \beta$.

*I hope it can help* ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind cooperation, which is greatly appreciated and supportive. I will get back to you as soon as I further in the process.